# Why does gradle api configuration not leak the dependency library?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I forked a copy of [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) library. It uses [libcommon](https://github.com/saki4510t/libcommon) as follows:

```
api("com.serenegiant:common:4.1.1") {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Please note `api` instead of `implementation` is used. [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) generates two aar files: libuvccamera-release.aar and usbCameraCommon-release.aar used by app Foo. [libcommon](https://github.com/saki4510t/libcommon) has interface IAspectRatioView. I can trace it with Android Studio for my branch of UVCCamera:

[image]

You can see the interface is from `com.serenegiant:common:4.1.1`. However, app Foo cannot reference IAspectRatioView:
[image]

I thought IAspectRatioView is supposed to be leaked by gradle api configuration.

However, I can trace declarations from AspectRatioTextureView of UVCCamera libary **within the app** project, I can see IAspectRatioView:

[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?